# Is this superfluous? -- "There would be fewer follies, >and< happiness and good feeling all around ..."

Tags: sentence-construction, coordination

> There would be fewer follies, **and happiness and good feeling all around** if we applied the scientific attitude to all our affairs.

Is it not superfluous to include ***and*** in "***and*** happiness and good feeling all around"?

Suggestions please.

Answer (score 4):

It may or may not be, depending on what the sentence intends to say. Without that first **and**, the sentence would contain a list of three items:

1. fewer follies
2. happiness
3. good feeling all around

The presence of that **and** means that there are instead two items:

1. fewer follies
2. happiness and good feeling all around

This is a different structure with subtly different meaning - it links 'happiness' and 'good feeling' into a single subject, and applies 'all around' to both.

Answer (score 3):

I believe that the author inserted the *and* there to make it clear that the word *fewer* is tied only to the word that immediately follows it, *follies*.  Without that *and*, it's possible that people would start to try to read it as a list of three things that there will be fewer of: "Fewer follies, fewer happiness, and fewer good feeling all around".  The ungrammatical nature of this list would then make the reader realize that the interpretation was wrong, but it's worth the extra word to avoid a potential mis-reading.

(Therefore, the *and* is not superfluous.)

Comment: Your answer and MrTheWalrus essentially say the same thing, but yours is clearer.

Answer (score -1):

Cut the and, and (I recommend) put a comma after happiness.  "Fewer follies, happiness, and good feelings"  are a list, and the joiner precedes the last item in the list.

OR

Change the first "and" to "with" so that it's clear the adjective "fewer" isn't supposed to apply also to "happiness" and "good feelings."

As "happiness" is generally considered to be a "good feeling," perhaps the most common example of one, "happiness and" is superfluous.